# Good node.js or python modules for streaming live video

Tags: video, python, node.js, streaming, http

Suppose I have a camera that streams video to an internet server. I want viewers to be able to see the live video on the browser. What are some software libraries and network protocols to use for this application? I can use either node.js or python for the backend. However, my preference is node.js